# DropDownListFor throwing error after posting the form

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Why can't I get this to work?

Controller:

```
List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>() {
new SelectListItem(){ Value="1", Text="Bohuslän"},
new SelectListItem(){ Value="2", Text="Dalarna"},
new SelectListItem(){ Value="3", Text="Dalsland"}
};

SelectList surbs = new SelectList(list, "Value", "Text");
ViewBag.Dropdown = surbs;
return view();
```

---

Uses a viewmodel

```
public class CreateViewModel
{
    public int SelectedId { get; set; }
    public Add Add { get; set; }
}
```

---

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedId, (SelectList)ViewBag.Dropdown)
```

---

Post to controller

```
public ActionResult Create(CreateViewModel adds)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Add add = new Add();
```

.
.

---

Error:

> The ViewData item that has the key 'SelectedId' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that after postback, the value of `ViewBag.Dropdown` is not retained and its value is `Null`, so it is throwing this error. Either Set the data in `ViewBag` again in your HTTP POST method like this:-

```
public ActionResult Create(CreateViewModel adds)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Add add = new Add();
            ------

   List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>() {
     new SelectListItem(){ Value="1", Text="Bohuslän"},
     new SelectListItem(){ Value="2", Text="Dalarna"},
     new SelectListItem(){ Value="3", Text="Dalsland"}
                                                        };
   SelectList surbs = new SelectList(list, "Value", "Text");
   ViewBag.Dropdown = surbs;
   return View();
```

You can wrap this inside a method to avoid code duplication.

Or the best approach in my opinion will be instead of passing the data in `ViewBag`, add a `SelectList` property to your ViewModel and then pass something like this:-

Updated ViewModel:-

```
public class CreateViewModel
{
    public int SelectedId { get; set; }
    public string Add { get; set; }
    public SelectList SurbsList { get; set; }
}
```

For Both Get & Post request, Bind your `SurbsList` like this:-

```
adds.SurbsList = GetSurbs();
```

Where, GetSurbs() is a method:-

```
private SelectList GetSurbs()
{
    List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>() 
                  {
                     new SelectListItem(){ Value="1", Text="Bohuslän"},
                     new SelectListItem(){ Value="2", Text="Dalarna"},
                     new SelectListItem(){ Value="3", Text="Dalsland"}
                  };
          return new SelectList(list, "Value", "Text");
}
```

And finally bind your dropdown like this:-

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedId, Model.SurbsList)
```

Comment: Used your code. I still got Additional information: The ViewData item that has the key 'SelectedId' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'. Everything works fine except post.

Comment: @ecuecu - Which approach you have followed? `ViewBag` or added the list to your ViewModel?

Comment: Viewmodel:    public class CreateViewModel
    {
        public int SelectedId { get; set; }
        public Add Add { get; set; }
        public SelectList SurbsList;
    }

Comment: @ecuecu - Okay so in your `HttpPost` method, you need to do this again  `adds.SurbsList = GetSurbs();` before returning the View.

Comment: Wow it worked, but i dont understand how it works. Im bindning a value to the post, and after i add some more listitems.

Comment: @ecuecu - On PostBack, ViewBag looses the data it holds, now since model binder won't bind the whole list, we need to send that list again when we return to same view(Ideally we return a separate view) so if you want you can add additional data to `SurbsList` after postback.